# Cournot Equilibrium

Tags: programming, functions, manipulate

I'm trying to determine reaction functions of a [Cournot equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cournot_competition) for $n$ firms using the same optimal condition, using the fixed point method.

This is the method I'm using:

```
fixedPoint[Gs_, X_, X0_, tol_, nmax_] := 
 Module[{G, sol, oldsol, iter, n, i},
  (*Vectors Gs and X must have the same length*)
  n = Length[X];
  G[s_] := Gs /. Table[X[[i]] -> s[[i]], {i, 1, n}];
  infNorm[s_] := Max[Abs[s]];
  sol = X0;
  oldsol = sol + 2*tol;
  iter = 0;
  While[And[iter <= nmax, infNorm[sol - oldsol] > tol],
   oldsol = sol;
   sol = G[sol];
   iter++];
  Print["Performed ", iter, " iterations"];
  If[iter >= nmax, Print["WARNING: Maximum number of iterations was reached"]];
  sol]
```

The equilibrium condition is (the derivative of profit with respect to quantity):

```
(((qt)^(-1/eta)) - (1/eta)*((qt)^(-1/(eta - 1)))*qi )-ai*q1 == 0
```

Where `eta` and `ai` are parameters, `qt` is the sum of the quantities produced by the $n$ firms, and `qi` is the quantity produced by a single firm.

So, my problem is determining the `Gs` argument of my method for $n$ firms. How do I generate $n$ optimal functions, each assuming its corresponding values for `ai` and `qi`?

Comment: (1) In your last equation, should `q1` be `qi`, or vice versa? (2) Is `ai` a firm-specific parameter in firm `i`s cost function, or is it a scalar parameter of inverse demand? (3) you should check the docs on built-in functions [FixedPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPoint.html) and [NestWhile](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html), and (4) Welcome to Mma.SE.

Comment: ... and the exponent in the second term should be `(-1/eta -1)`?

Comment: 1) you are right, q1 should be qi.
2)Exactly, ai is a firm-specific cost parameter. The cost function i'm using is (1/2)*ai*(qi^2)
3)I'll do that. Thank you. Yes, the exponent is (-1/(eta-1))

Comment: And let me add that the demand function is P(Q)=Q^(-1/eta).

Comment: Sorry for the imprecision, the exponent should be (-1/eta)-1.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear why you are going down this path. The wikipedia link contains all the derivations and for $n$ firms, using your variables, the solution, for all q's, is

$q=ai/eta*(n+1)$

and for the industry:

$Q=n*ai/eta*(n+1)$

```
ls = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 20};
ls1 = (10.*#)/(1 + #) & /@ {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 20};

xy = {#, 10. - #} & /@ ls1;

lines = {{0, 10. - #}, {#, 10. - #}, {#, 0}} & /@ ls1;

txt = MapThread[
   Text[Row[{Style["N", FontSize -> 8, Italic], 
       Style[" = " <> ToString[#1], FontSize -> 8]}], #2 + {0.4, 
       0.2}] &, {ls, xy}];

Plot[10. - Q, {Q, 0, 10},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1],
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Q", FontFamily -> "Times", Italic], 
   Style["P", FontFamily -> "Times", Italic]},
 Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[0.5], Line /@ lines, txt},
 Frame -> False,
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[1]},
 PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {0, 11}},
 Ticks -> None
 ]
```

[image]

For the case of duopolies you can graphically compare Bertrand and Cournot:

For Bertrand $Q$ is defined as constant and firms compete on price so taking a diagonal slice across quantities shows why there is a horizontal demand curve for each firm

```
pc = Plot3D[10 - q1 - q2, {q1, 0., 10.}, {q2, 0., 10.},
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
   AxesLabel -> {label1, label2, label3},
   ClippingStyle -> None,
   Exclusions -> {10 - q1 - q2 == 0},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   PlotRange -> {{0., 10.}, {0., 10.}, {0., 10.}},
   Ticks -> None
   ];

Show[pc, Graphics3D[{ 
   Polygon[{{0., 6., 0.}, {0., 6., 10.}, {6., 0., 10.}, {6., 0., 
      0.}}]}]]
```

[image]

For Cournot $Q$ is not defined as constant, but rather the $q$ of other firm(s) is constant so there is never a horizontal demand at the firm level under this model, even for very large $n$

```
pc = Plot3D[10 - q1 - q2, {q1, 0., 10.}, {q2, 0., 10.},
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
   AxesLabel -> {label1, label2, label3},
   ClippingStyle -> None,
   Exclusions -> {10 - q1 - q2 == 0},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   PlotRange -> {{0., 10.}, {0., 10.}, {0., 10.}},
   Ticks -> None
   ];

Show[pc, Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{0., 2., 0.}, {0., 2., 10.}, {10., 2., 
      10.}, {10., 2., 0.}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. I was following an unnecessary path. Thank you very much.